# Can I modify sms_body before sending SMS with built-in SMS Application?

Tags: android, sms

I know that we can send SMS via built-in SMS app in this way -

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));  
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But in my app, **I want to modify some text of the sms body before sending it** to the receiver. Is there any way?

I know **I can do it with sendTextMessage method of SmsManager**. I just want to know, is it also possible with the built-in SMS app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since SmsManager is part of frameworks. You cannot hijack it.

Edit:
What you could do is change your app manifest to recieve `ACTION_VIEW` and uri `sms:` just like default messaging app and then when launched will change the body and launch the default messaging app.

Edit: 
Add below intent filter to your app and then "sms_body" extra from the intent and rebroadcast it this time by createChooser

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: how I can receive 'sms:' in the manifest? Also can you give me some detail how can I change the body upon launch?