# Modifing SMS before sending in android

Tags: android, sms

I was wondering if it's possible to modify the SMS before sending it in Android, but not only if it's send by my application, but also if it's being send by other applications. My application would work in the background and wait for an sms sending, and when that occurres it prevents  it from doing so, modifies it and sends it.

For example, a default SMS application(built-in or otherwise) sends an sms to someone and I want to catch it before it does, modify the body(like add new receiver or some text inside message itself).

I think that this: [Can I modify sms_body before sending SMS with built-in SMS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185727/can-i-modify-sms-body-before-sending-sms-with-built-in-sms-application) might be an answer to my question, but I'm not sure, and it's kind of old.

Let me know if I was unclear in something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try with simple example-
Its just like you have an Account in a Bank and you wish all deposit should come in your Account. Here *Account* refers to your *App* and *Bank* refers to your *Mobile* device.

In a short, you can't achieve this on a non-rooted device. Yes that is possible on non-rooted device if user like to send his messages from your `App`, then surely you can modify messages written by user.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer, any idea on how could I achive it on rooted device or perhaps any guesses where should I look for the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> not only if it's send by my application, but also if it's being send by other applications

This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: I see your answers everywhere, could you please have a look at this question, if you don't mind ---- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294791/detecting-if-video-was-taken-in-portrait-landscape